# What is an office that keeps records of marriages and divorces called?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What is an office that keeps records of marriages and divorces called in English? I guess [Civil registry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_registry) is the general term, but what's the specific word for the above mentioned office?

Comment: Offices like this have different names in different countries. The Wikipedia article you yourself linked to gives a few of these; there is no universal name.

Comment: IN the US, this has several names. In the Us government system these records are kept at the _county_ level (Not federal, not state, but county). It could be a Vital Records office, a County Recorder's office, or County Clerk's office, or a whole bunch of other things.

Answer (score 4):

In Britain, this office is called the [***Register Office***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_office) (informally, *registry office*).

> A register office (frequently referred to as a "registry office" in non-official and informal use) is a British term for a civil registry, a government office and depository where births, deaths and marriages are officially recorded and where one can get officially married, without a religious ceremony. The term and function is also used in some parts of the former British Empire such as Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, India, and Jamaica, but not Canada.